# After Server update SP Config Wizard failed to connect SQL Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

After Server update I have run SP Config Wizard and it failed to connect sql server. How to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please mentioned, what issue you are getting.

Comment: unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain. Verify that the SharePoint container exists in the current domain and that you have rights to write to it.
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The object LDAP://CN=Microsoft SharePoint Products,CN=System,DC=abcdef,DC=com doesn't exist in the directory.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceConnectionPoint.Ensure(String serviceBindingInformation)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Active Directory administrator, creating a service connection point container will resolve the problem.

If not, you can run this command line:
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace v2v -passphrase "Type your Farm Pass Phrase" -wait

Reference：

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/11/psconfig-failed-unable-to-create-a-service-connection-point-in-the-current-active-directory-domain.html